# Find this $\frac{1}{2m+1}+\frac{1}{2n+1}=\frac{2}{2k+1}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let  $m,n,k\in \mathbb{N}$, and $m,n,k\ge 1,m\neq n\neq k\neq m $, such that
$$
\dfrac{1}{2m+1}+\dfrac{1}{2n+1}=\dfrac{2}{2k+1}
$$
Is there a solution? Or does this not have any solution?

Comment: Clearly, if there is one solution, there are infinitely many, by multiplying.

Comment: Smallest solution is $\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{15}=\frac{2}{5}$

Comment: Shouldn't this be tagged something like [tag:diophantine-equations] or [tag:elementary-number-theory] (looks better than [tag:number-theory])?

Comment: oh,Thank you arbautjc, Now this problem maybe have infinitely solution, can find this?

Comment: @math110, see Ishan's answer. Now, proving there are infinitley many *independant* solutions (in the sense that they would not be multiple of a smaller one) is another matter (and numerical tests tends to show it's also true). Maybe there is a *parametric* solution?

Comment: How about $p \not =q$, $$\frac{1}{2(4p^2+4pq+3p+q)+1}+\frac{1}{2(4q^2+4pq+3q+p)+1}=\frac{2}{2(8pq+2p+2q)+1}$$

Comment: @Ivan Loh,betieafull solution! Thank you my frend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{2a+1}+\frac{1}{(2a+1)(4a+1)}=\frac{2}{4a+1}$$
where $a>0$.

Answer (score 4):

In general

$$\frac{1}{u} + \frac{1}{v} = \frac{1}{n}, u,v,n \gt 0$$

can be solved as

$$n(u+v) = uv \iff (u-n)(v-n) = n^2$$

Thus you pick any factorization of $n^2$ and add $n$ to both factors.

If $n$ is odd, you get $u$ and $v$ to both be even.

So to solve your equation, you can solve the one I mentioned here, and all you need is to find $n,u,v$ such that $u = v = 2 \mod 4$ and $n = 1 \mod 2$.

(For instance, you can pick $n$ to be a product of primes of the form $4k+1$)

Comment: I remember a question which was asked in British Math Olympiad(Which I had gone through), quite similar to this. Something like : $\dfrac{1}{y}+\dfrac{1}{x}=\dfrac{1}{N}$ has $2005$ odd pairs $(x,y)$. We had to prove that $N$ is a square. Of course a hint to that problem (+1).

Comment: @Inceptio: Interesting question :-) Yeah, this works for that.

Comment: Yeah. $2005$ is the hint. Every square has **odd** number of divisors. It could be any odd. But the year was $2005$.:)

Comment: Basically, if $n$ is odd, you need a factor $D$ of $n^2$ such that $D\neq n$ and $D\equiv n\pmod 4$. Then $u=D+n$, $v=\frac{n^2}{D}+n$

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{1}{2m+1} +\dfrac{1}{2n+1}$, letting $2m+1$ to be the LCM of $2m+1$ and $2n+1$, Assume $2m+1=(2n+1) \cdot k$, your expression becomes $\dfrac{k+1}{2m+1}=\dfrac{2}{2l+1}$

$\dfrac{(k+1)}{2m+1}=\dfrac{2}{2l+1} \implies k+1=\dfrac{2(2m+1)}{2l+1}$. You just need a condition that $2l+1|2m+1$. Do you see that infinitely many solutions exists for this?

Comment: It's a little unclear how you can let $2m+1$ be the LCM of $2m+1$ and $2n+1$, unless you just mean that $2m+1$ is divisible by $2n+1$, or you mean $2d+1$ is the LCM for some $d$.

Comment: I mean $2n+1|2m+1$, For eg: $5,15$?

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1}{2m+1}+\frac{1}{2n+1}=\frac{2n+1+2m+1}{(2m+1)(2n+1)}=\frac{2(n+m+1)}{(2m+1)(2n+1)}$$

So this is of the form $\frac{2}{2k+1}$ if and only if $$(n+m+1)\mid(2m+1)(2n+1)$$

Now $(2n+1)(2m+1)=4nm + 2(n+m) + 1 = 4nm -1 + 2(n+m+1)$. So we want:

$$(n+m+1)\mid 4nm-1$$

Let $d=n+m+1$. Then $n\equiv -1-m\pmod d$ and therefore:

$$0\equiv 4nm-1\equiv 4(-1-m)m-1=-(2m+1)^2\pmod d$$

So $n+m+1\mid(2m+1)^2$, and, by symmetry, and $n+m+1\mid(2n+1)^2$.

Now assume $n<m$ and fix some $n\geq 1.$ We can find an $m$ if and only if there is a $d\mid (2n+1)^2$ such that $2n+1<d\leq(2n+1)^2$.  In that case $m=d-n-1$.

If $(m,n)$ is a pair satisfying this condition and $m>n$ then there is some factoring $(2n+1)^2=PQ$ with $P>Q>1$ and $m=P-n-1$.

So we are basically talking about factorings of odd squares in non-trivial fashion.

The general solution for this is $P=a^2c$ and $Q=b^2c$ with $a>b$, with $a,b,c$ odd. This yields the general solution, with $a,b,c$ odd and $a>b$:

$$2n+1=abc,2m+1=a(2a-b)c,2k+1=bc(2a-b)$$

The base case is when $c=1$ and $a>b$ are odd and relatively prime. Then $n=\frac{ab-1}{2},m=\frac{a(2a-b)-1}{2},k=\frac{b(2a-b)-1}{2},$ and we get: $$\begin{align}\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2m+1}&=\frac{1}{ab}+\frac{1}{a(2a-b)}\\
&=\frac{2a-b+b}{a(2a-b)b}\\
&=\frac{2}{b(2a-b)}\\
&=\frac{2}{2k+1}\end{align}$$

All other solutions can be found by dividing a base solutions by an odd integer.

When $a=2k+1$ and $b=1,$ you get the selected answer:

$$\frac{1}{2k+1}+\frac{1}{(2k+1)(4k+1)}=\frac{2}{4k+1}$$

Comment: Thank you my frend,@Thomas Andrews,This is good job!